# Space getting trim while extracting the PDF document using "pdfjs-dist" ( pdfjs ) package in nodejs Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf.js, esbuild, pdfjs-dist

while extracting the pdf document into text i'm getting an issue, its removing extra space and converting into single space Attached the pdf doc image for ref - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq0G9.png).

PDF data - "Cycle started Quick, 01/09/2023 12:03"

Example - "Cycle0started0000Quick,001/09/20230000012:03" after extracting into text "Cycle0started0Quick,001/09/2023012:03"

in the above example i represented spaces from 0

current version witch having the space issue is

`"pdfjs-dist": "3.11.174"`

The version i was using previously which doesn't have space issue

`"pdfjs-dist": "2.11.338",`

I'm using the below code to extracting the PDF document

```
import pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js';
import * as pdfWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';
import logger from './utils/logger.js';
import fs from 'fs/promises';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfWorker;

const pdfToText = async function ({ file, dataBuffer, startPage = 1, endPage = Number.MAX_VALUE, columnSeparator = '', rowSeparator = '\n', renderOptions }) {
    try {
        if (file) {
            dataBuffer = Uint8Array.from(await fs.readFile(file));
        } else {
            dataBuffer = Uint8Array.from(dataBuffer);
        }
        const doc = await pdfjs.getDocument(dataBuffer).promise;
        const result = {
            version: pdfjs.version,
            numPages: doc.numPages,
            metaData: await doc.getMetadata(),
        }
        result.info = result.metaData.info;

        endPage = Math.min(endPage, doc.numPages);

        const text = [];

        for (let pageNumber = startPage; pageNumber <= endPage; pageNumber++) {
            const page = await doc.getPage(pageNumber);

            const textContent = await page.getTextContent(renderOptions);
            let lastY, row = [];
            const pageText = [];
            for (const item of textContent.items) {
                if (lastY !== item.transform[5]) {
                    row = [];
                    pageText.push(row);
                    lastY = item.transform[5];
                }
                item.str = item.str.replace(' ', '*');
                row.push(item.str);
            }

            text.push(...pageText.map(row => row.join(columnSeparator)));
        }
        doc.destroy();
        result.text = text.join(rowSeparator);

        return result;
    } catch (err) { logger.error(`Error while extracting pdf doc ${err} : File name  ${file}`) }
}

export default pdfToText;
```

I have tried with different version of pdfjs-dist but is doesn't work i couldn't use the lower

Also i'm working with esbuild to bundling the application so i can't use the version lower then 3.11.174 it trow canvas error